# PL/SQL Trigger to check ticket date before inserting a row in Ticket table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

These are the tables and sequences I have created and I have inserted their values:

```
 CREATE TABLE Ticket_Type
  (
   t_type_id  NUMBER(1) PRIMARY KEY,
   CONSTRAINT check_t_type_id CHECK(t_type_id  > 0),
   t_type VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
   t_type_price NUMBER(4,2) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT check_t_type_price CHECK(t_type_price > 0),
   t_type_start_date DATE NOT NULL,
   t_type_end_date DATE,
   CONSTRAINT check_t_type_end_date CHECK((t_type_end_date IS NULL) OR (t_type_end_date >= t_type_start_date)),
   CONSTRAINT unique_t_type_t_type_start_date UNIQUE(t_type,t_type_start_date)
  );


 CREATE TABLE Screening
  (
   screening_id NUMBER(6) PRIMARY KEY,
   CONSTRAINT check_screening_id CHECK(screening_id > 0),
   plan_id NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
   theatre_id NUMBER(1) NOT NULL,
   screening_date DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE NOT NULL,
   screening_start_hh24 NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT check_start_hh24 CHECK(screening_start_hh24 BETWEEN 9 AND 22),
   screening_start_mm60 NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT check_start_mm60 CHECK(screening_start_mm60 BETWEEN 0 AND 59),
   CONSTRAINT unique_theatre_id_screening_date_screening_start_hh24_screening_start_mm60 UNIQUE(theatre_id,screening_date,screening_start_hh24,screening_start_mm60)
  );


  CREATE TABLE Ticket
  (
   ticket_id NUMBER(8) PRIMARY KEY,
   CONSTRAINT check_ticket_id CHECK(ticket_id > 0),
   t_type_id NUMBER(1) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT fk_t_type_id FOREIGN KEY(t_type_id) REFERENCES Ticket_Type(t_type_id),
   screening_id NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT fk_screening_id FOREIGN KEY(screening_id) REFERENCES Screening(screening_id),
   seat_id NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
   ticket_date DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT unique_screening_id_seat_id UNIQUE(screening_id,seat_id)
  );

CREATE SEQUENCE ticket_type_seq 
START WITH 1 
INCREMENT BY 1 
NOCACHE NOCYCLE;

CREATE SEQUENCE screening_seq 
START WITH 1 
INCREMENT BY 1 
NOCACHE NOCYCLE;

CREATE SEQUENCE ticket_seq 
START WITH 1 
INCREMENT BY 1 
NOCACHE NOCYCLE;

INSERT INTO ticket_type(t_type_id,t_type,t_type_price,t_type_start_date,t_type_end_date) 
VALUES (ticket_type_seq.nextval,'Adult',13.95,to_date('1/06/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY'),to_date('30/11/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY'));
INSERT INTO ticket_type(t_type_id,t_type,t_type_price,t_type_start_date,t_type_end_date) 
VALUES (ticket_type_seq.nextval, 'Concession',7,to_date('1/06/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY'),to_date('30/11/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY'));
INSERT INTO Ticket_Type (t_type_id,t_type,t_type_price,t_type_start_date)
VALUES (ticket_type_seq.NEXTVAL,'Student',7,TO_DATE('1/6/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'));

INSERT INTO Screening (screening_id,plan_id,theatre_id,screening_date,screening_start_hh24,screening_start_mm60)
VALUES (screening_seq.NEXTVAL,1,3,TO_DATE('11/9/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),9,0);
INSERT INTO Screening (screening_id,plan_id,theatre_id,screening_date,screening_start_hh24,screening_start_mm60)
VALUES (screening_seq.NEXTVAL,1,3,TO_DATE('11/9/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),11,0);
INSERT INTO Screening (screening_id,plan_id,theatre_id,screening_date,screening_start_hh24,screening_start_mm60)
VALUES (screening_seq.NEXTVAL,1,3,TO_DATE('11/9/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),13,0);
INSERT INTO Screening (screening_id,plan_id,theatre_id,screening_date,screening_start_hh24,screening_start_mm60)
VALUES (screening_seq.NEXTVAL,1,2,TO_DATE('11/9/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),13,0);
INSERT INTO Screening (screening_id,plan_id,theatre_id,screening_date,screening_start_hh24,screening_start_mm60)
VALUES (screening_seq.NEXTVAL,1,3,TO_DATE('11/9/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),15,0);
INSERT INTO Screening (screening_id,plan_id,theatre_id,screening_date,screening_start_hh24,screening_start_mm60)
VALUES (screening_seq.NEXTVAL,1,3,TO_DATE('11/9/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),17,0);
INSERT INTO Screening (screening_id,plan_id,theatre_id,screening_date,screening_start_hh24,screening_start_mm60)
VALUES (screening_seq.NEXTVAL,2,1,TO_DATE('11/9/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),9,0);
INSERT INTO Screening (screening_id,plan_id,theatre_id,screening_date,screening_start_hh24,screening_start_mm60)
VALUES (screening_seq.NEXTVAL,2,1,TO_DATE('11/9/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),12,0);
INSERT INTO Screening (screening_id,plan_id,theatre_id,screening_date,screening_start_hh24,screening_start_mm60)
VALUES (screening_seq.NEXTVAL,2,1,TO_DATE('11/9/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),15,0);
INSERT INTO Screening (screening_id,plan_id,theatre_id,screening_date,screening_start_hh24,screening_start_mm60)
VALUES (screening_seq.NEXTVAL,2,2,TO_DATE('11/9/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),9,0);
INSERT INTO Screening (screening_id,plan_id,theatre_id,screening_date,screening_start_hh24,screening_start_mm60)
VALUES (screening_seq.NEXTVAL,2,2,TO_DATE('11/9/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),15,0);
INSERT INTO Screening (screening_id,plan_id,theatre_id,screening_date,screening_start_hh24,screening_start_mm60)
VALUES (screening_seq.NEXTVAL,3,4,TO_DATE('11/9/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),9,0);
INSERT INTO Screening (screening_id,plan_id,theatre_id,screening_date,screening_start_hh24,screening_start_mm60)
VALUES (screening_seq.NEXTVAL,3,4,TO_DATE('11/9/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),12,0);
INSERT INTO Screening (screening_id,plan_id,theatre_id,screening_date,screening_start_hh24,screening_start_mm60)
VALUES (screening_seq.NEXTVAL,3,4,TO_DATE('11/9/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),15,0);
INSERT INTO Screening (screening_id,plan_id,theatre_id,screening_date,screening_start_hh24,screening_start_mm60)
VALUES (screening_seq.NEXTVAL,3,4,TO_DATE('11/9/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),18,0);
INSERT INTO Screening (screening_id,plan_id,theatre_id,screening_date,screening_start_hh24,screening_start_mm60)
VALUES (screening_seq.NEXTVAL,4,1,TO_DATE('11/9/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),18,0);
INSERT INTO Screening (screening_id,plan_id,theatre_id,screening_date,screening_start_hh24,screening_start_mm60)
VALUES (screening_seq.NEXTVAL,4,2,TO_DATE('11/9/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),18,0);
INSERT INTO Screening (screening_id,plan_id,theatre_id,screening_date,screening_start_hh24,screening_start_mm60)
VALUES (screening_seq.NEXTVAL,4,3,TO_DATE('11/9/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),19,0);
INSERT INTO Screening (screening_id,plan_id,theatre_id,screening_date,screening_start_hh24,screening_start_mm60)
VALUES (screening_seq.NEXTVAL,4,4,TO_DATE('11/9/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),21,0);
```

Now this is the question from the assignment:

**Create a trigger called TR_valid_15_min_ticket which should check ticket_date before inserting a row in Ticket table. The ticket issued date (ticket_date) can not be greater than the current date and time. In addition, it cannot be greater than screening time + 15 minutes. Otherwise, for each case, the trigger should raise a proper error. The error messages must be meaningful.**

**Hint: screening time = screening_date + (screening_start_hh24)/24 + (screening_start_mm60)/(24*60)**

**Note: ticket_date is in Ticket table and screening_date,screening_start_hh24,screening_start_mm60 are in Screening table**

**After trigger is successfully compiled, write SQL statements to insert data into the table for testing trigger. Both cases: you should insert valid and invalid ticket records in one theatre on the first day (11/09/2016).**

This is what I have tried:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_valid_15_min_ticket 
BEFORE INSERT
ON Ticket
FOR
EACH ROW
DECLARE
screening_time NUMBER;
v_screening_date Screening.screening_date%TYPE;
v_screening_start_hh24 Screening.screening_start_hh24%TYPE;
v_screening_start_mm60 Screening.screening_start_mm60%TYPE;
BEGIN
SELECT screening_start_hh24,screening_start_mm60
INTO v_screening_start_hh24,v_screening_start_mm60
FROM Screening
WHERE screening_id = :NEW.screening_id;
screening_time := v_screening_date + (v_screening_start_hh24)/24 + (v_screening_start_mm60)/(24*60);
IF (:NEW.ticket_date > SYSDATE) OR  (:NEW.ticket_date > (screening_time + 15))
THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,'Ticket date cannot be more than the current date nor can it have extra 15 minutes with addition to its screening time');
END IF;
END;
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Error(95,1): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(95,19): PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
Error(96,1): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(96,55): PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '>'
```

1. It would be really helpful if a correct solution trigger code is provided in order to correct the mistakes that I made in my code.
2. Based on this logic that I used: **IF (:NEW.ticket_date > SYSDATE) OR  (:NEW.ticket_date > (screening_time + 15))** , I know that I have to test the trigger by inserting a valid value and invalid value in ticket_date column in Ticket table by using INSERT statement. Based on **(:NEW.ticket_date > SYSDATE)** , I already know what invalid value or valid value I need to test it out for **(:NEW.ticket_date > SYSDATE)** . But for **(:NEW.ticket_date > (screening_time + 15))** , I don't know and I'm not sure what invalid value and valid value shall I enter to test out the trigger. It would be really helpful if a valid value and invalid value is provided based on **(:NEW.ticket_date > (screening_time + 15))**  , so that I can test it successfully.

Comment: i think, Error(95,19) is due to <number> := `<date>` + <number>. i.e. inconsistent types.

Comment: Screening_time should be of Type "Date"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Errors in your demo:

---

`CREATE TABLE Ticket_Type` doesn't work because `CONSTRAINT unique_t_type_t_type_start_date` name is too long - it can be up to 30 characters, but it is 31 characters long

---

`CREATE TABLE Screening` doesn't compile since this name is too long: `ONSTRAINT unique_theatre_id_screening_date_screening_start_hh24_screening_start_mm60 UNIQUE`, can be max. 30 characters

---

This expression causes `Error(121,19): PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type`

```
screening_time := v_screening_date + (v_screening_start_hh24)/24 
                  + (v_screening_start_mm60)/(24*60);
```

- `screening_time` is of type NUMBER
- `v_screening_date` is of type DATE
- `v_screening_start_hh24` is of type NUMBER
- `v_screening_start_mm60` is of type NUMBER

DATE + NUMBER gives DATE, so you cannot assing a DATE value (a result of the expression) to a NUMBER variable `screening_time`.

---

This line doesn't compile:

```
IF (:NEW.ticket_date > SYSDATE) OR  (:NEW.ticket_date > (screening_time + 15))
```

because of this expression:

```
:NEW.ticket_date > (screening_time + 15))
```

- :NEW.ticket_date is of type DATE
- screening_time is of type NUMBER

this comparision **DATE > NUMBER** doesn't make any sense, what should be a result for example of this expression: `2017-04-20 > 15` ?

---

> I'm getting confused whether to use :NEW.ticket_date > (screening_time
>   + 15)) or :NEW.ticket_date > (screening_time + (15*24*60))) ? –

Try to decompose these rules into simple steps, ii will be easier to understand and implement, like in this example:

```
DECLARE
   .....
   .....
   condition_1 BOOLEAN;
   condition_2 BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
  ......

-- The ticket issued date (ticket_date) can not be greater than the current date and time. 
   condition_1 := :NEW.ticket_date <= SYSDATE;

-- In addition, it cannot be greater than screening time + 15 minutes. 
   condition_2 := :NEW.ticket_date <= screening_time + interval '15' minute;

-- Otherwise, for each case, the trigger should raise a proper error. 
  IF  NOT ( condition_1 AND condition_2 )
  THEN
    --   The error messages must be meaningful.
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,'Ticket date cannot be more than the current date nor can it have extra 15 minutes with addition to its screening time');
  END IF;
```

Also, the requirement is `for each case, the trigger should raise a proper error.` so you have to have two separate error messages for each condition.

Comment: In addition, If you look at my trigger logic, I also used: SELECT screening_start_hh24,screening_start_mm60
INTO v_screening_start_hh24,v_screening_start_mm60
FROM Screening
WHERE screening_id = :NEW.screening_id;    Is this logic needed ? ... or shall I remove it.

Comment: now I have changed the data type of screening time from NUMBER to DATE as you have recommended.  Now my question is will  
:NEW.ticket_date > (screening_time + 15))  logic work now  ? .. since I have changed the data type of screening time to DATE. On the other hand, I'm getting confused whether to use :NEW.ticket_date > (screening_time + 15)) or :NEW.ticket_date > (screening_time + (15*24*60))) ?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a simple example how to do it.